# Got error IllegalStateException: already recycled once at ViewGroup.java class?

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception, viewgroup

Why IllegalStateException occur? (already recycled once)
This exception is coming from ViewGroup.java class and is unable to resolve that error.
And this crash did not occur in my device but the In users phone app crashes with a given exception.

> ViewGroup.java line 9606
>
> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: already recycled
> once
> at android.view.ViewGroup$TouchTarget.recycle(ViewGroup.java:9606)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3561)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
> at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:730)
> at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1922)
> at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:1008)
> at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:2)
> at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:688)
> at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:14644)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6519)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:6306)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5744)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5797)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5763)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5919)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5771)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5976)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5744)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5797)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5763)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5771)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5744)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8903)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8764)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8717)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9039)
> at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:194)
> at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java)
> at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:183)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:8979)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9066)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:996)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:794)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:722)
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:981)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)

Comment: Did you find the solution for same? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @hardik24 no i didn't find the solution

Comment: If anybody resolved this issue, please respond.

Answer (score 1):

did you debug **ViewGroup.java** ? putting debugger point in line 9606 ?
Would be better if you can post from what you are doing likewise. so the others can get some insight about giving you an answer! thanks